# Ошибка при создании пула в BitrixVM

Tags: php, битрикс, vmware

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой при создании пула в BitrixVM? Обрыл весь интернет, но вообще ничего не нашел по этой теме.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]